# Meteor js application cause stuck cpu 100%

Tags: meteor

i have a small meteor js  app suddenly it starts using 100% cpu. i found some blogs that says maybe oplog causing the height usage of the cpu so i've disabled it using:

```
    meteor add disable-oplog
```

but it did not changing anything. i'm facing this issue on the development environment  ( run the app through " meteor " command  ) and on the deployment environment (run the app remotly using mup ).
development environment : ubuntu 14.0 2G  64Bit meteor 1.3  node js 0.10.45.

deployment environment (droplet): ubuntu 14.0 512Mb  64Bit meteor 1.3  node js 0.10.45.

installed packages:

[image: installed packages]

monitoring process:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this problem before, but only when running too many production Meteor development enviornments on one server for too long.

It was the swap solution I put in place.  Meteor apps can use a lot of memory, and 512MB can be too little.  It was swapping all the time, which oddly showed up as a CPU spike.  Once I put a better swap configuration in place, all was fine.

This was on an Ubuntu server, I can't recall if it was 14 or 16.  On Digital Ocean hosting (they have Swap disabled by default, and the solution I put in place first was apparently bad).

It may not be likely this is the answer for you, but I'm writing it up as it's certainly possible, and can be very hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using CPU limiter here's a bash script I created
https://gist.github.com/cortezcristian/5ab4fdddcc573972d44873f1e97a2b88

You'll need to install cpu limiter first:

```
 sudo apt-get install cpulimit
 ps ax | grep node | grep meteor | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' > /tmp/my-app.pid
 cpulimit --p $(cat /tmp/my-app.pid) --limit 77
```

After that you can choose the limit you want 50 / 100 with the `--limit` flag.

Comment: thanks , i've scaled the digitalocean droplet from 512Mb to 1Gb also i did some optimisations for my functions (return and  exceptions) and deployed again now  its fine , the application still reach the 100 % when users interact  and i guess that's the nature of Meteor but it doesn't stuck there any more. Thanks again